# hero navigation - changing text for buttons

Tags: html

I have the following code, it changed the navigation bar depending on what page you are on.  Its fine except in one case I want to change the 4 buttons to five to names of cities (Rome, Vatican, Florance, Venice and Milan) when in italy.  How would I do that ?

```
 <!-- Hero nav section -->
    <div class="no-gutter">
          <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="<%= Application["baseURL"].ToString() + Session["lang"] + "/"+country+"/"+cityName+"/"+cityName+"-tours"%>"
                         <%if(url.Contains(cityName + "-tours")){%>class="current"<%}%>><% if (cityName == "washington-dc") {%>Washington, D.C.<% } else {%><%= cityName.Replace('-', ' ')%><%; } %> tours</a></li>
            <li><a href="<%= Application["baseURL"].ToString() + Session["lang"] + "/"+country+"/"+cityName+"/private-tours"%>"
                         <%if(url.Contains("private")){%>class="current"<%} %>>private tours</a></li>
            <li><a href="<%= Application["baseURL"].ToString() + Session["lang"] + "/"+country+"/"+cityName+"/nextday-tours"%>" 
                         <%if(url.Contains("nextday")){%>class="current"<%}%>>next day tours</a></li>
            <li><a href="<%= Application["baseURL"].ToString() + Session["lang"] + "/"+country+"/"+cityName+"/sale-tours"%>" 
                         <%if(url.Contains("sale")){%>class="current"<%}%>>sale tours</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

edit***

could i put in a if statement and select either italy or other  ? I have something like this for cities, but maybe i could change it for country ?

```
<% if (cityName == "rome")
            {%>
      <!--           <p>Explore the wonders of the “Eternal City” with City Wonder’s unique Rome tours. <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('rome').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">Read More</a></p> -->
            <%}%>
```

Comment: i would suggest to create a new menu for th cities you want and just switch menus if user is located in italy

Comment: I would suggest you to make a File/Database which contain name of the Cities, and Fetch those cities as per User locality.

Comment: thanks.. i will have to check that out first